# create ID based on a field with repeated entries in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a field that has single and repeated entries, let's say words:

| en | enid |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| building | 2 |
| can | 3 |
| can | 3 |
| water | 4 |
| water | 4 |

The field "en" contains words in English. The field "enid" is a field to be created which shall be populated with numbers based on the field "en" so that repeated words receive the same number.

Any idea how to automatically fill the field "enid"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `RowNumber` found at [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers):

```sql
SELECT 
    Words.en, 
    RowNumber([en]) AS enid
FROM 
    Words;
```

[image]

```vb
' Builds consecutive row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
' Optionally, a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID with an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID without an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID]), CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowNumber(vbNullString, True)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' 2020-05-29. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional ByVal GroupKey As String, _
    Optional ByVal Reset As Boolean) _
    As Long
    
    ' Uncommon character string to assemble GroupKey and Key as a compound key.
    Const KeySeparator      As String = "¤§¤"
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotRemoveKey   As Long = 5
  
    Static Keys             As New Collection
    Static GroupKeys        As New Collection

    Dim Count               As Long
    Dim CompoundKey         As String
    
    On Error GoTo Err_RowNumber
    
    If Reset = True Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys and group key counts.
        Set Keys = Nothing
        Set GroupKeys = Nothing
    Else
        ' Create a compound key to uniquely identify GroupKey and its Key.
        ' Note: If GroupKey is not used, only one element will be added.
        CompoundKey = GroupKey & KeySeparator & Key
        Count = Keys(CompoundKey)
        
        If Count = 0 Then
            ' This record has not been enumerated.
            '
            ' Will either fail if the group key is new, leaving Count as zero,
            ' or retrieve the count of already enumerated records with this group key.
            Count = GroupKeys(GroupKey) + 1
            If Count > 0 Then
                ' The group key has been recorded.
                ' Remove it to allow it to be recreated holding the new count.
                GroupKeys.Remove (GroupKey)
            Else
                ' This record is the first having this group key.
                ' Thus, the count is 1.
                Count = 1
            End If
            ' (Re)create the group key item with the value of the count of keys.
            GroupKeys.Add Count, GroupKey
        End If

        ' Add the key and its enumeration.
        ' This will be:
        '   Using no group key: Relative to the full recordset.
        '   Using a group key:  Relative to the group key.
        ' Will fail if the key already has been created.
        Keys.Add Count, CompoundKey
    End If
    
    ' Return the key value as this is the row counter.
    RowNumber = Count
  
Exit_RowNumber:
    Exit Function
    
Err_RowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotRemoveKey
            ' GroupKey is not present, thus cannot be removed.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_RowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```